# How to send parameter with AJAX(not Jquery AJAX) and receive it with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm trying send some AJAX(not Jquery AJAX) parameter to a server with HTML form values and store it a database. But it doesn't work correctly. When i hit the Let's start button i have got my error message
Here is my code....

```
<div class ="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12" id ="AJAXsignup">
        <h3>Creating a new account...</h3>

        <input class ="form-control" type ="text" name ="fullname" placeholder ="Type your name eg:-Jhon Smith" id ="namefull">
        <span class ="label label-warning" id ="err_fullname">You should type your name</span>

        <input class ="form-control" type ="text" name ="username" placeholder ="Type your user name eg:-Jhon 95" id ="nameuser" style ="margin-top:5px;">
        <span class ="label label-warning" id ="err_username">Missing username</span>

        <div class ="input-group">
        <span class ="input-group-addon">@</span>
        <input class ="form-control" type ="email" name ="email" placeholder ="Type your Email" id ="email" style ="margin-top:5px;">
        <span class ="label label-warning" id ="err_email">Missing email</span>
        </div>

        <input class ="form-control" type ="password" name ="password" placeholder ="Type your Password" id ="pass" style ="margin-top:5px;">
        <span class ="label label-warning" id ="err_password">Missing Password</span>

        <input class ="form-control" type ="password" name ="password" placeholder ="Repeat your Password" id ="repass" style ="margin-top:5px;">
        <span style ="margin-bottom:5px;" class ="label label-warning" id ="err_repass">Repeat Password</span>

        <img class ="col-sm-offset-5 col-md-offset-5 col-lg-offset-5" src ="images\Preloader_2.gif" id ="loader" style ="display:none;" style ="margin-bottom:5px;">

        <input class ="btn btn-lg btn-info col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" type ="submit" id ="btn" value ="Let's start!" style ="margin-bottom:5px;" onclick = "validate()">

        <input class ="btn btn-lg btn-danger col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"type ="button" id ="frm-can" value ="No.Thanks">

    </div>
```

The JAVASCRIPT code

```
function sendinginfomation(){
    if(window.ActiveXObject){
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }else{
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    var fullname = document.getElementById('namefull').value;
    var user_n = document.getElementById('nameuser').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var user_p = document.getElementById('pass').value;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",'php/signup.php?w='+fullname+"&n_p="+user_n+"&tv="+email+"&q="+user_p,true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState ==4){
            $("#loader").fadeOut(300);
            document.getElementById('AJAXsignup').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

The PHP code

```
$fullname = $_GET['w'];
$username = $_GET['n_p'];
$email = $_GET['tv'];
$password = $_GET['q'];
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=reg_mem",$username);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO mem_info(Full_name,User_name,Email,Password) VALUES($fullname,$username,$email,$password)";
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "The infomation sent sunncessfully.";
    }catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "The infomation unable to send right now";
    }
```

Comment: which error you getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Jquery ajax** to send var to the **PHP** page.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET", (or POST)
        url: "code.php",
        data: { fullname, user_n, email },
        cache: false,
        success: function(){
      }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send information with the GET method, add the information to the URL:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "filename.php?fname=value&lname=value", true);
xhttp.send();
```

To POST data like an HTML form, add an HTTP header with setRequestHeader(). Specify the data you want to send in the send() method:

```
xhttp.open("POST", "filename.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("fname=value&lname=value");
```

[Refer this link for more details](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line from HTML.

```
        <input class ="btn btn-lg btn-info col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" type ="submit" id ="btn" value ="Let's start!" style ="margin-bottom:5px;" onclick = "validate()">
```

To

```
        <input class ="btn btn-lg btn-info col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" type ="submit" id ="btn" value ="Let's start!" style ="margin-bottom:5px;" onclick = "sendinginfomation()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your `onclick="validate()"` to `onclick="sendinginfomation();"` OR you can call 2 function on click like `onclick="sendinginfomation();validate();"`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `validate()` is working correctly and the `sendinginfomation()` is called from within the `validate()` function I made a working copy of your code. I found an error in `$("#loader").fadeOut(300);` . If you havn't included `jQuery` you cant call `fadeOut()`. But if you have already included `jQuery` there is no need for javascript function, you can use the jQuery ajax itself.

Other than this your code is working fine.